# Как переключится на другого пользователя в github

Tags: git, github

Делаю по инструкции

```
 create a new repository on the command line
    echo "# allbs_marketplace" >> README.md
    git init
    git add README.md
    git commit -m "first commit"
    git branch -M main
    git remote add origin https://github.com/deniswebsites/allbs_marketplace.git
    git push -u origin main
```

Выводит ошибку

```
$ git push -u origin main
remote: Permission to deniswebsites/allbs_marketplace.git denied to postolenko.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/deniswebsites/allbs_marketplace.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Мне нужно переключиться с postolenko на deniswebsites. Делаю вот так

```
git config --global user.name "deniswebsites"
git config --global user.email "denisfrontend@gmail.com"
```

При вводе команды

```
$ git push -u origin main
```

Выводит опять ошибку 403 как и выше. Что можно сделать?

Comment: вам надо не имя с почтой менять, а ssh-ключ. А можно и не менять, а просто поставить общий для двух аккаунтов.

Comment: кстати, нахрена вам вообще два аккаунта?

Comment: Из-за конфликта с Россией не приходит верификационный ключ на яндекс почту. Пришлось сделать новый аккаунт с gmail почтой. Вот теперь нужно на него перейти.

Comment: А как поменять ssh ключ